# Temple run 2 crash - lost my characters

Tags: temple-run-2

I had characters Cleopatra, Mrs. Claus, Wolfman, a skeleton among others plus new outfits for bunny guy, mummy bones, Vampire Lee, etc. among the rest.

The game crashed and reset all characters, and I lost most. Still have the hats and artifacts and objectives but lost all gems and coins. I'm more upset about losing all my characters and outfits. Is there a way to get these back?

This game is on my Samsung 4 phone.

Comment: The short answer, is no

Answer (score 0):

All characters mysteriously all returned.  Very happy. Got back Imhotep, Cleopatra, Mrs Claus, Sigur Frostbeard, Freya Coldheart,  Francisco Montoya, Sir Montague, Wolf man and all outfits for the others.  Strange how they all came back. Only lost my progress in the global challenge and all my gems and coins. Very unusual.